# What's the difference between Readyboost+Suprefetch vs Pagefile (or Linux Swap) on a flash drive?

Tags: windows-7, readyboost, superfetch

What's the major difference between new technologies and placing pagefile on a separate flash drive? It seems to me that new technologies are just wrappers. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can't ever put a pagefile on a flash drive! (What an idea.)

A pagefile can only exist on the system drive and is used for application code "overflow" when memory is full, as well as for the memory dump for a BSOD.

Readyboost is an old technology from the days when memory was costly, small and slow, intended to augment RAM memory with disk space. Do not use.

Superfetch is a technology to preload often-used applications into memory in order to speed their startup times, mostly for slow laptops.

Conclusion: They are not wrappers, but technologies meant to improve the performance of hardware-challenged computers.

Comment: A pagefile can be stored on another drive than the system drive (although it complains about memory dumps if you have no pagefile at all on the system drive). But it's right it should not be stored on a flash drive (if it even can), a flash drive is way too slow.